# Remove #pragma once warnings

Tags: c++, pragma, gcc-warning

I am using `#pragma once` in my `.cpp`s and `.hpp`s and because of that I get a warning for each file that uses it. I have not found any option to disable this kind of warning, only the thing of `#ifndef MY_FILE_H #define MY_FILE_H /*...*/ #endif`.

So would you recommend me to replace each `#pragma once` with `ifndef`s?

in header:

```
#define MYFILE_H
// all the header
```

and in the other files:

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#include "myfile.hpp"
#endif
// the rest of the file
```

What do you think, is it better to use it like this? Or there is an option to disable the `#pragma once` warnings in GCC, that I do not know?

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? Maybe it's an old one that doesn't support `#pragma once`?

Comment: There were old versions of GCC that complained about pragmas that it didn't know about. The C99 and C11 standards require (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.10.6 Pragma directive): _Any such
`pragma` that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored._  Since pragmas cause problems for you, especially if the compiler doesn't recognize it and you include the header more than once, but the header guards work everywhere, use the header guards. Compilers are normally clever enough to spot the header guards.

Comment: Just an info: if you need to remove warnings of unknown `#pragma`s, use the `-Wno-unknown-pragmas` flag

Comment: What's the exact warning message? `#pragma once in main file`? Related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89808 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563679/gcc-precompiled-header-pragma-once-in-main-file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The common approach is to place the guard in the .h file only:

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H
// all your myfile.hpp here
#endif
```

or

```
#pragma once
// all your myfile.hpp here
```

The rest of files (other .cpp) should do nothing regarding the guards. You should not get warnings by doing this.

Comment: I'd just like to add that it should be 
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H
// all your myfile.hpp here
#endif

Comment: He may be using an outdated version of GCC (pre 3.3) which could still generate the warnings for `#pragma once` usage, though this is unlikely.

Comment: @ssell: No, the problem was because I was using the `#pragma once` in `.cpp` too

Comment: @BlackBird true, I forgot.

Comment: Or both.  In networked systems, `#pragma once` is not always reliable, so you need the include guards anyway.  (Even if all your files are currently on a local drive, that might not be the case in the future.)  And if one of your targets is VC++, `#pragma once` will make a significant difference in compile times.  (For other compilers, it probably doesn't change anything.)

Answer (score -5):

Indeed the `#ifndef` guard can always be used, but just to remove the warning while compiling the source which uses `#pragma once` I would recommend to use the `-w`option while compiling.

e.g. `gcc -w -o <output file> <input file(s)>`