# disable warning for pragma once

Tags: gcc, pragma

I am using `pragma once` in my `.cpp` files.

However I am always having a warning `#pragma once in main file`.

How to disable it? I am using `GCC 5.1.0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove #pragma once warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135538/remove-pragma-once-warnings)

Comment: I need this too, I filled a bug with gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89808

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is a way.

Putting `#pragma once` in the main file isn't actually useful.  `#pragma once` it used in a header to prevent the header from being included more than once.

Note that `#pragma once` is unavoidably slower than using the straightforward and portable header guard style:

```
#ifndef something_h
#define something_h
... header text here
#endif
```

So I would recommend simply not using it ever.

Comment: Well...In order to do things faster for now I don't use headers and just create classes inside namespaces in .cpp files. So in order to prevent redefinition errors I added `#pragma` directive.

Comment: [Some folks disagree with you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787539/4019986).

Comment: it's not slow, in bug report there is used symbolic link instead of files, which results in another inclusion. So it's not slow, it's buggy test application.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `-w` compile option to remove this warning.

e.g. `gcc -w -o <output file> <input file(s)>`

Comment: what does `-w` stand for?

Comment: The -w option inhibits the warning. Refer [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)

Comment: Well, it disables *all* warnings. While your solution is correct, I would appreciate if your wording includes a warning (haha) that each and every warning will be turned off.

Comment: @FrederickNord The answer was compiled with `-w`.