# gcc precompiled header: pragma once in main file

Tags: c++, g++, pragma, precompiled-headers

I created a header file. Something simple as follows.

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void say(T t) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

and then use `g++` to create the `gch` pre-compiled header with `g++ hello.h`. It gives me this warning ->

```
pch.h:2:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
    2 | #pragma once
      |         ^~~~
```

But the `gch` file created and the pre-compiled header works fine. This error goes away if I use header guards.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What version of `g++` are you using? Have you found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135538/remove-pragma-once-warnings)

Comment: I tried with g++-5 to g++-9 and they all produce the warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong; this is a quality of implementation issue that [has been mentioned on the issue tracker before](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64117#c0) (but, to my knowledge, there are currently no plans to change the behaviour).

In Clang, you could turn off the warning for that particular compiler invocation (with `-Wno-pragma-once-outside-header`); in GCC you'll just have to grin and bear it for now.

Comment: Also related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89808

Comment: Not just "grin and bear it", but also turn off `-Werror`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The main source file used to generate a precompiled header is usually a made-up "indirect" header that contains only a bunch of #include for all the actual real headers you want to precompile.
When you use the machinery this way, there is no need for a #pragma once (nor guard) in the main file, and hence it works as intended with no warning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known GCC bug:

- [Pragma once warning when compiling PCH](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47857)

To my knowledge, there is no good way to disable this warning. One way that retains matching behavior is an additional indirection.  In `pch.h`, use

```
#include <pch-real.h>
```

(without `#pragma once`), and store the actual header contains in `pch-real.h`. This mostly preserves the include-only-once optimization even if `<pch.h>` is included multiple times in non-PCH mode.