# Cryptic error message when using a makefile

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, build-error, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to force GCC to use the precompiled header (`pch.h`). But I am getting an error:

```
.
.
.
g++ -c -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -H -O3 -flto -include pch.h PeykNowruzi.cpp
! ./pch.h.gch

mingw32-make: *** [makefile:10: PeykNowruzi.o] Error 1
```

This is my makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -H -O3 -flto

all: PeykNowruzi

PeykNowruzi: PeykNowruzi.o Util.o CharMatrix.o
    $(CXX) PeykNowruzi.o Util.o CharMatrix.o -o runPeykNowruzi

PeykNowruzi.o: PeykNowruzi.cpp CharMatrix.h pch.h.gch
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -include pch.h PeykNowruzi.cpp

Util.o: Util.cpp Util.h pch.h.gch
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -include pch.h Util.cpp

CharMatrix.o: CharMatrix.cpp CharMatrix.h Util.h pch.h.gch
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -include pch.h CharMatrix.cpp

pch.h.gch: pch.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) pch.h -o pch.h.gch

clean:
    rm *.o runPeykNowruzi
```

First of all, GCC does not name the header as `pch.h.gch` and instead it names it as `pch.h`. When I manually delete all the **.o** files and the **.exe** and the **pch.h**(the .gch one, not the .h one), then run make, it builds succesfully. But when I rename the precompiled header to `pch.h.gch`, it fails as I showed above. Also when I remove the `pch.h`, then I expect it to compile it again before compiling other source files (which depend on pch.h). I run make, it compiles `pch.h`, then starts to compile `PeykNowruzi.cpp` and fails.

I fix this problem by deleting `.o` and `.exe` and `pch.h` files altogether and then running make again.

Am I doing something wrong that I should not do? And why GCC on my Windows machine does not name the precompiled header as `pch.h.gch`?

**EDIT**: Regarding my 1st question, I just found out that Windows 10 *File Explorer* was hiding the extension of all files. I checked a box and now it shows the precompiled header as `pch.h.gch`.

Comment: Are all header files, including `pch.h`, properly guarded?

Comment: Also note that the three `.o` Makefile rules are missing a corresponding output argument `-o name.o`.

Comment: @Marc Stevens All header files have `#pragma once` at each of their first lines.

Comment: There is another question where it seems precompiled headers might have problems with #pragma once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563679/gcc-precompiled-header-pragma-once-in-main-file You could try the usual header guards using `#ifndef`.

Comment: @Marc Stevens >"Also note that the three .o Makefile rules are missing a corresponding output argument `-o name.o`."  Wow, this solved my issues!